# Read/write on USB port in C++

Tags: c++, api, usb, read-write

My arduino is communicating with a simulator that is running on a PC. I would like to make a small API between the two.

My entire code is in C++. I would like to add this communication pattern to have a real time communication. Can you give some clue how I should proceed?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You should proceed by searching the internet for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

If the aruduino connects as a virtual serial port, you should be able to communicate by opening the serial port object as a file. Under Linux, that would be `/dev/ttyUSBX` or something like that.